# functions in makefiles?

Tags: makefile

I have a slew of makefile targets that do the same thing:

```
${SOME_FILE}:
    ${FILES} | ${DIST_DIR}

    @@cat ${FILES} |                     \
        sed 's/@DATE/'"${DATE}"'/' |     \
        sed 's/@VERSION/'"${CR_VER}"'/'  \
        > ${OUT_FILE};
```

where `${FILES}` and `${OUT_FILE}` are the only things changing.  I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to simplify these targets to something like:

```
${SOME_FILE}:
    compile(${FILES},${OUT_FILE})
```

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GNU make has this:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function

To define a multi-line function, you would use this syntax:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes

Comment: Using define ... endef does nothing for me. It just ignores the line completely. I tried using $(var-name) and $(call var-name). I can just use a single line variable though and wrap the lines with a semi-colon, ;, and a backslash, \. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my GNU make version is 3.81.

Comment: Important note: when you define a function that calls `$(MAKE)`, you must add the `@+` after the equality sign. So like: `sub_make = @+$(MAKE) -C $(TOPDIR)/subdir/$(1) $(2)`. Otherwise make [won't pass descriptors and options it ought to to submake calls](https://flameeyes.blog/2008/11/16/for-a-parallel-world-case-study-n-4-jobserver-unavailable/), which would manifest itself as a `warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.`

Answer (score 29):

Links to docs (like in the accepted answer) are good but good example is better :)

```bash
define my_func
    $(eval $@_PROTOCOL = "https:")
    $(eval $@_HOSTNAME = $(1))
    $(eval $@_PORT = $(2))
    echo "${$@_PROTOCOL}//${$@_HOSTNAME}:${$@_PORT}/"
endef

my-target:
    @$(call my_func,"example.com",8000)
```

Take into consideration the following:

- There are no custom "functions" in Makefile language. So "my_func" is actually a variable that simply contains a text.
- That "function" doesn't have its own scope. All the content of that "function" is copied into the recipe as is. All variables in the body will be used after that as a part of the recipe.
- Don't use spaces near the commas to prettify param list of "call" function.
- Args are passed like $(1), $(2), ... that is not very handy, so re-declare them with meaningful names. This is optional but recommended for bigger "function" bodies.
- Variables are declared with `$@_` prefix that makes them "local" to the rule (actually not local but prefixed by the target name).

So we have imitation of functions with imitation of local variables but generally this works good.

Comment: I took inspiration from this answer to write a gist: https://gist.github.com/lulingar/f84ab70b86b37104dbbd7be0581c69ed

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to restrict yourself to GNUmake, your best bet is probably to generate makefile fragments yourself and then `include` them.