# Warning "forced in submake" in parallel execution of make

Tags: parallel-processing, cmake, makefile

When I run `make -j3` to build in parallel, I get

```
warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
```

In the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) I found the warning is emitted

> if make detects error conditions related to parallel processing on
>   systems where sub-makes can communicate.

What are these error conditions? What can I do to heal them or suppress the error message?

The makefile is generated from CMake, so I cannot (=I don't want to) edit the makefile.

Comment: How do you run child Makefile in your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: I think that only CMake is calling make and submake. But after your question I am not longer 100% sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually this message occurres if you call make from your Makefile not by the variable $(MAKE)

Example:

Change

```
foo:
     cd foo/ && make foo
```

to

```
foo:
     cd foo && $(MAKE) foo
```

Comment: I did not write the makefile myself, it is auto-generated by CMake.

Comment: cmake usually does this right, maybe you are calling make from CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Well, in my case this is exactly how I call the submake. I have a function `sub_make = $(MAKE) -C $(TOPDIR)/subdir/$(1) $(2)`, and then I do e.g. `$(call subproject,all)`. So it is `$(MAKE)` as you say. And still I get the warning.

Comment: Okay, [I figured the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783243/functions-in-makefiles#comment113020403_6784014). It turns out, for some reason `$(MAKE)` call won't work as it should if you call it from a Make function. In such cases the function must have `@+` symbols after equality sign. So, given my previous example, to make it work I'd have to declare it as `sub_make = @+$(MAKE) -C $(TOPDIR)/subdir/$(1) $(2)`

Answer (score 3):

You call `make -j3` for you top-level Makefile, which means that up to 3 targets can be built simultaneously (*make* uses 3 threads to build). Your top-level Makefile (generated by *CMake*) run another *make* (which is called sub-make). And in this invocation another `-jN` option is used. So instead of using common jobserver for both *makes*, sub-make uses another N threads to build its targets. So up to `3 + N` threads in total are used for building. So this is what this warning about.

To enable common jobserver for parent *make* and sub-make, there are 2 requirements:

- Explicit `-jN` option mustn't be passed to sub-make. Call sub-make without this argument.
- Sub-make must be called using `$(MAKE)` expression (not just plain `make`). Alternatively the `+` prefix can be added before `make` command. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60702726/5447906) for details.

If both requirements are satisfied, then, when you run `make -jN` for you top-level Makefile, parent *make* and child *make* use N threads in common for building.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to multi-threaded make feature. It happens when there is yet another multi-threaded make inside a make process that is already multi-threaded. As there is second level of multi-threaded make, the internal synchronization is not available.

It is possible to fix this by -j parameter.

```
make -j 1
```

The code above will avoid multiple thread and it will remove the warnings.

Again, we can use `-j` parameter in the makefile as well.

```
target:
    $(MAKE) -j 1 -C ${SUBDIR} $@
```

The above rule will not spawn threads for `submake` and it will avoid the warning.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these insights. But with CMake generates the Makefiles and I don't have control over them. As it seems to be fixed in upstream CMake and/or GNU make, I am fine with this topic.

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of GNU make (4.0) and CMake (2.8.6 and 3.3) I can no longer reproduce the warning. One of these got fixed in the meantime.