# An elegant way to handle multiple extensions in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a small C++ language project consisting of several source an header files, and I use Makefile to build my project.

Recently I added a .c file in my project that originally had only .cpp files. To build the whole project including the .c file, I revised my Makefile like:

```
SRC_DIR     := src
INC_DIR     := include
BUILD_DIR   := build

C_EXT       := c
CPP_EXT     := cpp
SOURCES     := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -name *.$(CPP_EXT))
               $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -name *.$(C_EXT))       # Added!

...

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(CPP_EXT) $(INC_DIR)/%.h
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
                    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INC_DIR) -c -o $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(C_EXT) $(INC_DIR)/%.h                 # Added!
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)                                             # Added!
                    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INC_DIR) -c -o $@ $<         # Added!
```

But I think it's little ugly because there is duplication of commands. Is there any way to remove the duplication and improve this Makefile commands?

Comment: If you're going to compile them with the same compiler rather rename the files else change.c to use $CC

Comment: @Waslap  It is also a crucial information. Thx :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make comes with default rules for building C and C++, so for basic usage you wouldn't have to worry about this.  Since you're changing the rules to create a more sophisticated build tool, you might want to just bite the bullet on a little bit of duplication (in your example it's not that much).  You could put stuff like this in a common make `include` file and use it for all of your similar projects -- that way it isn't cluttering your project-specific makefile.

---

However...

GNU make does have provisions for [defining](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) and [calling](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function) functions, although they may be obscure.

```
define do_compile
    @mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
                    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INC_DIR) -c -o $@ $<
endef

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(CPP_EXT) $(INC_DIR)/%.h
    $(call do_compile)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(C_EXT) $(INC_DIR)/%.h                 # Added!
    $(call do_compile)                                                 # Added!
```

---

Related: [functions in makefiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783243/functions-in-makefiles)

Comment: If you want want to get even fancier, look into the `-MM` option to gcc -- it helps you manage a more specific dependency tree so you don't have to recompile everything just because any include file changed.   Be warned though, doing this does introduce some new challenges.